# How to punctuate a sentence that begins with a list, then explains it?

Tags: punctuation, anacoluthon

I want to know what to do when a list and the clause that introduces it are reversed. For example:

> The wrinkles around his eyes, the deep lines that marked his brow, the gray streak at his temples[?] everything he saw in his reflection told the story of a long life he didn't remember living.

My first inclination was to use an em dash, but I couldn't find any specific rules concerning this particular usage. Since the list isn't an independent clause, I'm fairly certain it wouldn't be a colon; still, I can't shake the nagging feeling that there's a better way to punctuate it.

I'd be grateful for any help you can give me!

Comment: Not putting this in as an answer as I have nothing to back it up with, but I would go with an em dash.

Comment: AKA "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama" or "A man, a plan, a canal—Panama"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe colons are generally accepted with pure enumerations. An m-dash would be my first choice though, mostly because the enumeration precedes its introductory clause, as you say. I believe it would be the conventional choice; the step from enumeration to "everything" would be considered an anacoluthon.

> The wrinkles around his eyes, the deep
>   lines that marked his brow, the gray
>   streak at his temples—everything he
>   saw in his reflection told the story
>   of a long life he didn't remember
>   living.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect either an em-dash, a colon, or possibly a semicolon, depending on the urgency of the emotion that you wish to convey.  With no other context to guide me, I'd say that the em-dash would have a connotation of surprise at what he was seeing, the colon would be neutral, and the semicolon would be contemplative.